# How to apply Filters on publishing stream

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, recorder

I've developed a Flash video recorder(using AS3, Flex) which captures live web cam and streams to Wowza media server.

I am trying to apply sharpness, contrast, saturation and sharpness filters on the live video being captured.

I am able to apply filter effects on the video being captured on the screen. How do we apply the filters so that it reflects in the stream being published ?

Thank you in advance
Rajesh

Comment: afaik it's possible only on client side. however you may pass all filter settings via NetStream.send() and apply them on the other side

Comment: Could you please refer me to any example with any media server ?

Comment: For example, how to achieve this using flash media server.

Comment: i don't have any expirience of handling it on server side: never had a chance to try it. however as far as i know FMS uses actionscript, so it sholdn't be hard. i'll post an answer with example of NetStream.send() via adobe stratus (2 flash apps connected p2p)

Answer (score 0):

this code is from the test app that was made to research adobe stratus features and that repeats basic functionality of skype
here's the handling class:

```
public class RecievingObject extends Object
    {        
        public function RecievingObject(){

        }        
        public function message(str: String):void {
            ChatWindow.addText('>> ' + str);
        }
    }
```

and how it's attached to the stream (the whole class except `NetStatusEvent` handlers that do nothing):

```
    public final class Streams
    {

        private static var streamOut: NetStream;
        private static var streamIn: NetStream;

        public static function initIn(id: String): void {
            streamIn = new NetStream(Main.connection, id);
            streamIn.client = new RecievingObject();
            streamIn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onInStatus);
            streamIn.receiveVideo(true);
            streamIn.receiveAudio(true); 
            streamIn.play('media');
            VideoWindow.initIn(streamIn);
            Mixer.initSound(streamIn);
        }

        public static function initOut(): void {
            streamOut = new NetStream(Main.connection, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
            var peerConnected:Object = new Object();
                peerConnected.onPeerConnect = function(subscriberStream : NetStream) : Boolean {
                    var oo:RecievingObject = new RecievingObject();
                    subscriberStream.client = oo;
                    if(!streamIn){ initIn((subscriberStream as NetStream).farID); }                    
                    return true;
                }
            streamOut.client = peerConnected;            
            streamOut.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onOutStatus);            
            streamOut.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
            streamOut.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
            streamOut.publish('media'); 
        }


        public static function send(data: String): void {
            if(streamOut) { streamOut.send('message', data); }
            ChatWindow.addText('<< ' + data);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Sure, again what do we need to do on the server side after passing the params.

Comment: @ Rajesh : is there a certain player that plays your stream? if yes there're two ways: 1. find a way to call `NetStream.send()` for each connecting client and handle it in the `NetStream.client` 2. put the filter settings into some xml file on the server and make clients read it on start (or maybe every certain amount of time - if you're going to change filters at runtime)

Comment: 1) Video will be saved on the media server in flv format. 2) we will facilitate user to retrieve this flv file. 3) user may transcode this file and can play in any player which they have. 3) Thus the filters must be applied to the video stream and can't be stored seperately and applied whenever they play it(no restriction where user wants to playback the video).